# dataExporter (Excel and CSV) not exporting the dataTableCommandLink values - PrimesFaces and JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, export, lazy-loading

I have few columns in the Data Table which displays the column name and row values dynamically.
But the first column in the data table have the values which has link. when we click that value it redirects to other screen.

Problem is when we export the csv/excel report. The first column which has this hyperlink not displaying the exact values. it shows as below in the excel

org.primefaces.component.column.Column@72d586ad - instead of exact value like "S123456789"

Please suggest how to display the exact value in the excel and csv.

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['column.header']}" width="100" styleClass="columnLeft" filterBy="#{sampleDTO.linkNum}" sortBy="#{sampleDTO.linkNum}" id="linkNum">
                            
 <e:dataTableCommandLink id="viewTestLink" index="#{index}" value="#{sampleDTO.linkNum}" bean="#{sampleListBean}" action="viewLinkViewer"
                                                    ajax="false" currentDto="#{sampleDTO}"/>
```

</p:column>

Thanks in advance
Nithyn K

Comment: What version of PF? I feel like this was fixed a long time ago?

Comment: its 6.2 version

Comment: I am using PF 7.0 and my column has `<p:link id="lnkUrl" href="#{splunkUrlProvider.getSplunkUrl(row)}" value="#{row.eventCorrelation}" target="_splunk" />` and it exports fine as the value in `value`.

Comment: this it will  work in 7 version, even i read in forum. But in 6.2 still the same issue. Is there any other work around ?

Comment: Can you post your exact `<p:column` code above in your issue?

Comment: Added above my code

Answer (score 2):

OK the reason its happening is because you are using a custom component `<e:dataTableCommandLink` which is why it can't figure out what text to display.

Here is what I would do use the `ExportFunction`...

1. Create a custom exporter my example uses CDI.

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class PassthroughColumnExporter {

   public String export(final UIColumn column) {
      String value = StringUtils.EMPTY;
      for (final UIComponent child : column.getChildren()) {
         final Object exportValue = child.getAttributes().get("data-export");
         if (exportValue != null) {
            value = String.valueOf(exportValue);
            break;
         }
      }

      return value;
   }
}
```

2. In your XHTML use this custom exporter to export the value you want looking for the `data-export` attribute.

```xml
<p:column exportFunction="#{passthroughColumnExporter.export}">
    <e:dataTableCommandLink value="#{row.displayValue}" data-export="#{row.exportValue}" />                 
</p:column>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Code Sharing, I have added the above code but when ever i try to hit the excel icon its not even hitting my PassthroughColumnExporter- export method. And this Custom Exported do we need to add in this package org.primefaces.extensions.component.exporter? I have added outside of this package as well inside as well, still the hit not comes to this export method.Please let me know if i need to add anything

Comment: Well `#{passthroughColumnExporter.export}` has to be an accessible bean.  I use CDI which is why mine uses @Named not sure if you are using Managed beans or what.

Comment: I have given you the tools, now its up to you to debug and figure out what's not working.